# C# getting the type from an inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class which I'm using more as an interface. Part of my code takes in the abstract class but I need to figure out which of the class that inherit for it it is so that I can populate a List using that class.

```
abstract class thingy
{
    //methods, variables, etc
}

class awsomeThing : thingy
{
    //Imagine there are more of these classes with different names...
}
```

I'm limited to passing in the abstract class (thingy) as the type but need the `awsomeThing` type from it? How do I go about doing that?

**EDIT**

Too clarify what I'm looking for in the answer the class that is using the `awsomeThing` has a method close to this:

```
void Start(thingy wantedType){

    List<thingy> collectionOfStuff = new List<thingy>( );

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        //Here I want to add the type awsomeThing or one of the other classes
        //that derive from thingy but I don't know which one it is

        collectionOfStuff.Add(new ????); //what is wantedType in reality?
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just calling [GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your object?

Comment: @ManoDestra Thing is how do I get the type and add a new thing of that type too a list?

Comment: If you have an object `awsomeThing obj = new awsomeThing();`, then it's just `obj.GetType();`

Comment: And just have a List<thingy> to store the awsomeThing objects, or any other objects that subclass thingy.

Comment: I can't imagine a practical implementation for something like this.  Honestly if you have an ABC or Interface passed to the function then you shouldn't have to know the derived type.  In my opinion, the types should all implement the interface, and if you have to do something specific based on the derived type then you should be starting with that type.  This type of question could result in an endless debate about proper OOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the object type via GetType method.

You could also add virtual method to your base class returning some enum which would allow you to determine actual object type.

Another option is to use [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) as a condition in your if statements where you need to determine your object type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing some concepts regarding OOP. If you use abstract class as an interface, you should use an interface (or more interfaces). They are not the same concept. You should use as much interfaces as you need for your domain, instead of using a huge all-purpose interface (or abstract). Its called Interface Segregation Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Regarding your question, you can create a List of interface type and also abstract types. In your case, if you want to use the base abstract type as the type of your collection, you should remember that "All classes inheriting the base class should have the same behaviour as using them as base classes", as per Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: I know about interfaces and abstract classes. I'm using an abstract class because all the functions that I would declare in the interface are identical for each class. So rather than wasting 60 lines of code per class I simply implemented it once in the abstract class.

Comment: Good software design is never wasted lines of code :) Saying that you're using an abstract class because you don't want to rewrite your code, does not make it correct. And again, they're not the same. Also, with productivity tools like Resharper, you don't have to rewrite everything again.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to worry about what type you are populating the list with**

Just create a list of type `List<thingy>`

```
var ls = new List<thingy>();

//Add any object that inherits from thingy
ls.Add(new myAwesomeThingy());

//Or add whatever other type of object that implements myThingy
ls.Add( new AnotherClassThatInheritsFromMyThingy());
ls.Add( new WhatThatGuySaid() );
ls.Add( new Ditto() );

//If you want to get only the items of type myAwesomeThingy do this
var nls = ls.OfType<myAwesomeThingy>().ToList();

//this will print one
Console.WriteLine(nls.Count);

//This will print out type name "myAwesomeThingy"
Console.WriteLine(nls[0].GetType());
```

**Based off of your Edit**

If you want to create a new instance based off of a passed argument you can do the following :

```
void Start<T>(T wantedType) where T : new(), thingy
{

    List<thingy> collectionOfStuff = new List<thingy>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        //here I want to add the type awsomething or one of the other classes
        //that derive from thingy but I don't know which one it is

        collectionOfStuff.Add(new T()); //Will create based off the passed type of T
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know (thats what I want to do :D) but the problem is that I'm limited to getting the type from a variable. For now it looks like I'm going to have to make an enum which tells me which type it is, i was hoping to get a solution which is a bit cleaner...

Comment: limited by whom?  Is this a homework assignment?  In my opinion, that solution is the cleanest of all the answers.  I'm not sure what getting the type from a variable even means, but if that is a requirement then you should have written that into the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define an abstract factory method and implement it in each of the inherited classes to return a new instance of itself e.g.:

```
    class Thingy
    {
        abstract Thingy CreateInstance();
    }

    class AwesomeThingy : Thingy
    {
        override Thingy CreateInstance()
        {
             return new AwesomeThingy();
        }
    }
```

Then you can just use that in your method:

```
    void SomeMethodThatPopulatesAListOfThingy(Thingy t)
    {
        var list = new List<Thingy>(Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i=>t.CreateInstance()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   BaseItem item = new Item();
   Console.WriteLine(GetBaseType<Item>().Name); // BaseItem
   Console.WriteLine(GetImplementerType(item).Name); // Item
}

static Type GetBaseType<T>()
{
   return typeof(T).BaseType;
}

static Type GetImplementerType(object obj)
{
   return obj.GetType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the abstract class like an interface, maybe it should be one ;-)

Here's an alternative to the `GetType()` call: you can implement this in a generic way; the code execution is faster than calling the `GetType()` method during run time.

The property `GetGenericType` returns the type of your inherited class:

```
abstract class Thingy<T> where T : Thingy<T>
{
    //methods, variables, etc

    public Type GetGenericType => typeof(T);
}

class AwsomeThing : Thingy<AwsomeThing>
{
    //Imagine there are more of these classes with different names...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thingy t = new awsomeThing();
if (t is awsomeThing) Console.WriteLine("My type is awsomeThing");
```

The Output is "My type is awsomeThing"